# How to stop deployment to the android emulator?

Tags: android, emulation

I created a test app. It builds. Here's the code:

```
 using System;
 using Android.App;
 using Android.Content;
 using Android.OS;
 using Android.Runtime;
 using Android.Widget;
 using System.IO;
 using Android.Database;
 using OpenFileTest;

 namespace OpenFileActivity
 {
     [Activity(Label = "OpenFileActivity")]
     public class OpenFileActivity : Activity
     {


     private const int FilePickerRequestCode = 1;
        protected internal Button openFile;
        protected override void On

    Create(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                openFile = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.openFile);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        
                Button openFileButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.openFile);
                openFileButton.Click += OpenFileButton_Click;
```

}

```
private void OpenFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
    intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
    intent.SetType("*/*"); // Set the MIME type to allow opening all file types
    StartActivityForResult(intent, FilePickerRequestCode);
}

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == FilePickerRequestCode && resultCode == Result.Ok && data != null)
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
            string filePath = GetPathFromUri(uri);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            {
                // Read the file content
                string fileData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

                // Now you have the file data in the 'fileData' variable
                // You can process it further as needed
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetPathFromUri(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        string[] projection = { Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data };
        ContentResolver cr = ContentResolver;

        using (ICursor cursor = cr.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null))
        {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {
                int columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);
                return cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

When I try to run it on my phone (which is plugged in and is the deployment choice) Visual Studio starts the emulator and tries to deploy to that. How can I stop VS from using the emulator?

I have another Android app under development and when I run it, it is deployed to the phone and available.

i can kill the emulator by running this:

adb -s emulator-5554 emu kill

But why does the VS select the emulator?

Comment: Have you tried running the command `adb devices` to see if your physical device shows as available?  Normally, the emulator will only start if there are no available devices.

Comment: Yes, the phone is attached. ADB finds it. AND sometimes the app is deployed to my phone. but mostly the emuator starts. (BUT Even so I can't find it on the phone. It's in the Apps folder, but nowhere else.)

Comment: The emulator starts up several times even though the phone (Samsung A51) is the choice.